How can I fully understand the literal meaning of common phrases like 有り難う御座います？
How can I fully understand the literal meaning of common phrases like 有り難う御座います？
Besides knowing the meaning of phrases like those in real life and just remembering them as a whole, I'm really interested in understanding what it means literally and what each part separately mean and how it forms a phrase or sentence. Are there resources that have reliable explanations on those?
I searched Internet and common dictionaries for this particular example, so far, the most useful one is https://hinative.com/questions/22487201, but as there are multiple answers, which have somewhat different explanations and details, I still don't fully know the answer.

See etymology here. In this context, ございます is a politeness marker, similarly to です.

I will try my best to explain here.
First, we know that 有り難うございます　is just あり＋がとう＋ございます, and let's look at them one by one.
有り is just the verb meaning to have, or to exist. It's meaning is no different from its meaning in the sentence 本が有る.
The word 難{がた}い means difficult, and is attached to the verbs' stem (the ます form, if you will) to mean, it's difficult to do XXX. For example, 離れる is to leave, 離れ難い is "difficult to leave", either physically to emotionally. ある is to exist, ありがたい is, then, "difficult to exist"
In Classical Japanese, い-adjective did not end in い, but rather ended in き or し depending if they are used in front of the noun (赤い馬 -> 赤き馬) or after the noun (馬は赤い -> 馬は赤し). Thus, the proper way of saying ありがたい in Classical Japanese is ありがたし. In fact, you still here ありがたし here and there in modern Japanese, especially when it comes to literature.
We know how to make a い-adjective into negative, right ? 赤い becomes 赤くない. Well, turns out, we can also use the form 赤くある to state the positive form of the adjective, just like we say 馬は赤い, we could also say 馬は赤くある. This grammar is a bit old-fashion and dated but you can still find it in literatures or lyrics.

正しくありたい、あれない、寂しさが… from the song 間違い探し by 菅田将暉

Thus, combining what we learned, in order to say "it's difficult for (your action) to exist", or "it's difficult for you to have done that", thus "thank you", we should say 有り難くあります. Then, since ございます is a more respectful version of　あります, we say 有り難くございます instead.
Wait! that's still not 有り難うございます, is it? Well, it turns out that 有り難くございます would be the standard way to say it, except for that Kyoto was the old capital of Japan, and since the people there were considered to be more mannerful, the standard Japanese just absorbed the Kyoto dialects when it came to greetings. That's why we have 有り難うございます which is the Kyoto way of saying 有り難くございます, which, in turn, just means ありがたい (or ありがたし). Also for お早うございます, that's also just お早{はや}くございます which technically just means, well, 早いです. The お and the ございます just adds layers of respect without changing the core meaning.

I know that 難く is gataku but 難う is gatou, and お早う is ohayou but 早く is hayaku. It's not the く get replaced by う but the entire aku gets replaced by ou

Or more precisely, /k/ was elided, and some time later, consecutive 2 short vowels turned into long vowels (where originally outcomes of [au] and [ou] were different, but they merged later). I mentioned rules of this monophthongization e.g. here in section 3. So e.g. 遍く (amaneku) → 遍う (amanyō); 嬉しく (uresiku) → 嬉しゅう (uresyū).
